# Nslookup in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to run this code to perform Nslookup in python with inputs given in command line. But, i cannot get the DNS ips. can someone help me out?

```
import os
a=input("enter a ip address")
print(a)
print (os.system('nslookup' +a))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space, and as such, the command is being passed to the OS as "nslookup8.8.8.8"

Try this:

```
import os
a=input("Enter a IP address: ")
print(a)
print (os.system('nslookup ' +a))
```

Comment: Good to hear! Would you mind marking the answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

The valid command is `nslookup ipaddress`.

So in your code give a space between `nslookup` and the `ipaddress` while giving command to `os.system(command)`

The valid statement would be

```
print (os.system('nslookup ' +a))
```